# Kubernetes PodAffinity not able to deploy pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

So I have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65313780/kubernetes-how-to-config-a-group-of-pods-to-be-deployed-on-the-same-node), and try to implement `podAffinity` to solve it.

I have 3 nodes and want to deploy 2 pods on the same node. In the `Deployment` YAML files I have `service:git` under `metadata.labels`, and the following is the affinity setting:

```
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: service
            operator: In
            values:
            - git
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

But the pods failed to deploy, I got the following error:

```
0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match pod affinity rules, 3 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity.
```

Are there any problems with my configuration?

If not, I guess maybe it is because when the first pod is deployed, the system will try to find a node that contains a pod with the label `service: git` and fail (because it is the first one), and another pod also fail because of the same reason. Is this correct?

But then how to solve the problem (without resorting to workarounds)?

Comment: You should label the desired nodes with a key value pair `service=git`, like `kubectl label nodes <your-node-name> service=git`...with that in place the node affinity should work 

Comment: But the problem is I don't care which node it is, the target is to put the two pods on the same node, do I still need to do that?

Comment: @Hackerman , it would not help  because scheduler is looking for a pod whose label is "service=git" not a node with that label.

Comment: Why is it important to you that the pods be on the same node?  Can you just delete this constraint, and let the scheduler run the pods wherever they happen to fit?

Comment: @DavidMaze, please check my use case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65313780/kubernetes-how-to-config-a-group-of-pods-to-be-deployed-on-the-same-node, the reason is they are using the same persistentVolume in a storage class only allow "ReadWriteOnce", meaning only one node can access

Answer (score 4):

- You are using "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:" so it will be looking a "running(already)" pod which has a label "service: git" and itseems you do not already have any pod with that label. so following a is a quick workaround where a test pod will be created with label "service: git" . so that podAffinity rule will find a destination node ( that would be the node where this testpod will be running)

`kubectl run testpod --image=busybox --labels="service=git" -- sleep infinite`

- Once above pod is UP .. all the pods in your deployment also should get created.
  if not delete the deployment and re-apply it.
- If you need a elegant solution then you can consider using "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution" instead of "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution"

Comment: Thanks @confusedgenius for the solution, I think maybe I have made a mistake here -- instead of adding the labels `service: git` under `spec.template.metadata.labels`, I did that in the `metadata.labels` of the `Deployment` itself. Changing that seems to solve the problem, without any workarounds. But your solution is also very great.

Answer (score 0):

Update Sept 2022:

The "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:" is effectively ignored when it is the first pod of the deployment and the pod does in fact get scheduled - otherwise if no pods are there then not even the first one will be able to be deployed. The second pod will then obviously see that first pod running and satisfy the rule and so on. This has been confirmed by testing.